# Setting A Header Image for a Wordpress Page and all its children

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress.  I've got a handful of pages, each with children -- varying depths.

Let's say it's like this:

```
+about
-- page1
-- page2
+stuff
-- page1
--- sub-sub-page
-- page2
```

My problem:
I want to set a graphic header for all the "about" pages, including all its children... and a different graphic header for all "stuff" pages and all its children.

I *could* do this using a custom field for each individual page, but I don't trust my users to remember to set this field.

I thought about adding to the page.php template and telling the page to find its parent top-level page to determine which "family" it's in, then set the header graphic that way...but I don't want to invest a ton of time (and run-time) resources traversing up the hierarchy.

Any ideas?

Much thanks in advance...

**UPDATE:**

Taking the code from below, I modified it to use outside of the Wordpress Loop (have not yet integrated the "default" value yet).

```
    <?php 
    global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;

$header_swf = get_post_meta($postid, 'header_swf', true);

if (!$header_swf) {
    $parent = get_page($wp_query->post->post_parent); //array of values for this page's parent, directly above it

   while (!$header_swf && $parent) {
        $header_swf = get_post_meta($parent->ID, 'header_swf', true);
        $parent = get_page($parent->post_parent); //new parent
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This answer assumes (perhaps incorrectly) there is no built-in method to do this.*

You could write something in the template that looked for a predefined custom field. If none exists, it could ask the parent page for its version of the custom field, and so on.

```
$val = get_post_custom_values('header_image');
if (!val) {
    $parent = get_page($post->post_parent);
    while (!$val && $parent) {
        $val = get_post_custom_values('header_image', $parent->id);
        $parent = get_page($parent->post_parent);
    }
    if (!$parent && !val) // has failed to find a header image!
        $val = 'my default value';
}
```

Or something like that.....

I should point out that might be really database heavy so it might be worth caching the value for each given URL. I'd personally recommend memcached but there are other methods.

Comment: Is there a way to set a default fallback in this?  Just in case a page gets created without a parent or without the value?

Comment: I've just added a couple of fixes to the code if you're trying to play with it, but yes! I'll just make another edit now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say test for the current page's family. I wouldn't think it'd be too taxing, as it's just a simple short-circuit.

Here's [a previous SO thread on how you'd accomplish this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891238/wordpress-php-way-to-test-if-pages-are-children-of-a-parent-page).